# TypeOrm - How to set relational field to null

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, typeorm

I am trying to set `categoryId` of my entity `ProductTORM` to `NULL` when the `category` gets softRemoved through transactions.

```
await tManager.save(ProductTORM, {
    ...productToUpdate,
    categoryId: null,
    category: null,
});
```

ProductTORM Entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class ProductTORM {
    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToOne(() => CategoryTORM, (category) => category.products, {
        nullable: true,
    })
    category?: CategoryTORM | null;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true })
    categoryId?: string | null;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

However, there is no error on execution. And everything in transaction works perfectly. But the code above won't simply do anything.

Is there anyway to keep typesafety with foreignkeys and change the value to NULL through TypeOrm?
Thanks in advance!

I even cannot delete the key manually. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWdeo.png)

The only way I could've set it to NULL was through query from DBeaver console.
Although it did not work through query with TypeOrm function. It was again just ignored.

Initially I used MySQL DB and switched to MsSQL DB because I though it could solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the cascade option in the relationship field. Also, I would use the JoinColumn annotation:

```
@Entity({ name: 'products' })
export class ProductTORM {
    .
    .
    .

    @ManyToOne(() => CategoryTORM, (category) => category.products, {
        nullable: true,
        cascade: ['soft-remove', 'recover']
    })
    @JoinColumn({name: 'categoryId'})
    category?: CategoryTORM | null;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

With that, the ORM will do the stuff by you.

Think this will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I found the principle of my problem.

This is my non function code (update function is ignored):

```
// This find category without changes
const category = await tm.findOrFail(categoryId)

// This change row in DB to categoryWithChanges
await tm.update({...category, somechanges})

// This NOT ONLY update the deletedAt column but the whole entity.
// I used the initial const category which still has no changes. So it basically reverted the whole update.
await tm.softRemove(category)
```

The easiest solution could this:

```
const category = await tm.findOrFail(categoryId)
await tm.update({...category, somechanges})

const updatedCategory = await tm.findOrFail(categoryId)
await tm.softRemove(updatedCategory)
```